# Two computer MAC Addresses

Tags: ifconfig

In Ubuntu 14.04, when I run the command `ifconfig | grep HWaddr` to know the mac address of my computer, I find two MAC addresses, how is it possible?

```
zina@zina-HP-Pavilion-g4-Notebook-PC:~$ ifconfig | grep HWaddr
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a4:5d:36:71:61:d9  
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 24:fd:52:e1:9b:4d
```

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/203789/what-is-the-active-mac-address-of-my-computer

Answer (score 6):

MAC addresses belong to network adapters, not computers.  Your computer has a wireless interface (wlan0) and a wired interface (eth0).  Each has its own MAC address.

If you're connected to a wired network, the MAC address that everyone else sees is the first one.  If you're on wireless, it's the second one.

Comment: On running `ifconfig | grep HWaddr`, I see a third entry besides `eth0` and `wlan0`: `pan1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 76:40:d6:7b:56:2b`. Any idea what that's about?

Comment: "the MAC address that everyone else sees"... on the local network, of course, as it won't go any further.

Comment: @DKBose The pan1 interface is a software interface used to bridge the Wifi and LAN connector together (only used when you make a Wifi connection a Wifi router and share this connection with another computer that connects to your laptops wired connector).  You may also see hardware-addresses linked to Bluetooth and Firewire connections. These can be used as network interfaces too.

Comment: @Tonny, are you sure that `pan` is used for anything else apart from Bluetooth?

Comment: @jcaron With IPv6 that's not entirely true anymore. Self-generated Ipv6 addresses often embed the mac-address. So mac-addresses can get exposed wider than the local LAN, albeit in a non-Ethernet way.

Comment: @jcaron Read carefully. I didn't say that. Actually you can use pan also to bridge a Bluetooth nic with another nic. But I explicitly mentioned WiFi to LAN because that is the most common case.